# How to correctly add a Java Maven project dependency to a Grails Maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, grails, groovy

I'm using:

- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2
- M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.xxx
- Grails 2.1.2
- Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.4.0

My approach was to create a Grails application, then convert it to a Maven project and then I added a Java Maven project as dependency through the "Java Build Path" -> "Projects" option.
But every time I want to run the Grails application the Grails application is unable to resolve those classes from my other Java Maven project.
Might be a very simple problem but I couldn't find any solution so far.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with not being able to resolve changes to classes in a separate Maven module. What worked for me is this:

- Add the dependency to pom.xml of the Grails project (so that you can build outside the IDE)
- Do **not** add the Maven nature to the Grails project. The other projects will still have the Maven nature, but the Grails project should not.
- In Properties for the Grails project, choose Java Build Path -> Projects and add the other Maven projects. This allows Eclipse to immediately find changes to the other project.
- Start Grails with JRebel enabled (so that you can reload changes to Java classes in the separate Maven modules)

The above steps allows for smooth reloading of classes in GGTS 3.4 and Grails 2.1.2 without rebuilding jars or restarting the server. It might be that the Maven integration improves in later versions so that the workaround above is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 11):

I think a better approach would be publishing your jar into your local repository, then you can add your dependency into your grails application by configuring BuildConfig.groovy:

1) Add your local maven repo to your project:

```
repositories {
    inherits true
    checksums false
    grailsPlugins()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    }
```

2) add your dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile: "<your_group_id> : <your_artifact_id> : <version>"
...
}
```

When you're launching your project in grails env, it will download automatically your jar

Comment: No you cannot refer a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy for a mavenized grails project. The dependency has to go to pom.xml.

Comment: I agree, but as generic approach i would recommend to use that method if you can keep the grails dependencies builder instead of a maven pom. It has some advantages like reliability and will be compatible with next grails releases (gradle should appear soon following the grails 3.0 roadmap).

Comment: Usually the developer tells you the maven repo to add: `maven { url "https://..." }` and the compile command needed as the answer said.

Answer (score 2):

The library Project has to be a Maven project and then you have to add the dependcy into your pom.xml file in the "Main" project.

the dependencies part of your project could look like this

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>your-library-project-group</groupId>
            <artifactId>your-library-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <version>your-library-version</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```